# Displaying multiple objects with same keys in Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I currently have a dictionary property `scoreDictionary constructed so that it contains values that are themselves a nested dictionary:

```
{
    Bob = {
        "2013-08-02 00:27:02 +0000" = 70;
        "2013-08-02 00:28:17 +0000" = 60;
    };
    Robert = {
        "2013-08-02 02:53:19 +0000" = 1137;
    };
    Mooga = {
        "2013-08-02 02:53:04 +0000" = 80;
    };
}
```

I am able to return the correct number of rows for the required method `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:`, but have trouble when writing the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Specifically, since there must be **two** rows showing the same key "Bob", but with different score and date information, how do I deal with `indexPath.row` so that it is able to return different information for the cell each time its called despite having the same key?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you not want sections? You could make each name be a section with how ever many rows you need for the inner dictionary.

Comment: You should post more of your code. Show us what you are doing for numberOfRowsInSection and what you currently have for cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you want the output to look like. If you want sections, with the name being the section title, you could do it like the following. Because of your data structure, getting to the right piece of data is complicated looking (it would be a lot easier with an array of dictionaries).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theData = @{@"Bob":@{@"2013-08-02 00:27:02 +0000":@70, @"2013-08-02 00:28:17 +0000":@60}, @"Robert":@{@"2013-08-02 02:53:19 +0000":@1137}, @"Mooga":@{@"2013-08-02 02:53:04 +0000":@80}};
    self.keys = self.theData.allKeys;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"sections are: %d",self.keys.count);
    return self.keys.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.theData[self.keys[section]] count];
}

-(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.keys[section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.theData[self.keys[indexPath.section]] allKeys][indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.theData[self.keys[indexPath.section]] valueForKey:[self.theData[self.keys[indexPath.section]] allKeys][indexPath.row]] ];
    return cell;
}
```

This give this output (using a right detail cell type):

[image]

If you don't want section titles, you can just delete the titleForHeaderInSection method, and change the cellForRowAtIndexPath method to this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *name = self.keys[indexPath.section];
    NSString *date = [self.theData[self.keys[indexPath.section]] allKeys][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",name,date];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.theData[self.keys[indexPath.section]] valueForKey:[self.theData[self.keys[indexPath.section]] allKeys][indexPath.row]] ];
    return cell;
}
```

The only problem is that for longer names, the date and time string is too long and cuts off the number value. So, you would either need to shorten that string, or go to the subtitle type of cell where that number will be on a separate line.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and thank you for including the screenshots!  I was wondering - if I didn't want section titles, but rather one section with all the rows (and so each row would display the name, date and score), how would I be able to realize this?  My thought is to use "invisible" sections, and show the section titles in each of the cells.  I suppose my follow up question is - how would I be able to show the section names in my cells as well, but not actually show the section titles?

Comment: @daspianist, I've added to my post to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a section for each Name (key) of your dictionary. In each section, the row would be the entries date/value.

Even if you want your rows to be together, just don't implement any header of the tableview, because this solution/organization with the tableView is far the best to your problem.

If you want any help with this approach, let us know so we can show some code to guide you.

Answer (score 0):

As per your example NSDictionary(scoreDictionary), in tableview to show two indexpath row under section 'Bob' and to show one indexpath row under section 'Robert'and 'Mooga' follow sample code as bellow

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView {

    return [[scoreDictionary allKeys] count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [[scoreDictionary valueForKey:[[scoreDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:section]]count];

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [[scoreDictionary allKeys]objectAtIndex:section];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {




    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *tempScoreDic = [scoreDictionary valueForKey:[[scoreDictionary allKeys]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] ];


    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempScoreDic valueForKey:[[tempScoreDic allKeys]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[tempScoreDic allKeys]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;




}
```

Comment: This would do, except that you have a (maybe) undesireable behavior of changing the order of the sections everytime he loads the tableView, because dictionary doesn't preserve order. He would have to sort the allKeys array by name in viewDidLoad, for example